# how to start a new project

Tags: java, web-applications, project-structure

For the first time ever I am getting the chance to start a new project.

I am comfortable with structure of the project with regards to the 'development'. It has the usual  'src', 'lib', 'resources', 'test', etc dirs. I already have this structure in the Eclipse project.

I am unable to decide what should be the dir structure in the source control.  I am currently thinking the following:

```
/sourcecontrol/branch/MyProject:
-dev
---- Here I will have dirs that make up the 'Eclipse' project.
-dbscripts
---- sql Scripts for any DB Schema change
-documentation
---- UserGuide.pdf
---- DeveloperGuide.pdf
---- Other such docs
-sh
---- Here I will have the scripts to deploy, start, and stop the web server.
-notes
---- Here I will store random 'helpful notes' that developers can create for other developers.
```

The idea is that when somebody wants to just 'develop' the project, they can check out only the 'dev' dir.

Is this a good idea? Any suggestions from your past experience? I have been unable to find 'best practices' for a new project that don't talk about 'src', 'test', 'lib', etc.

EDIT:
If it helps, its a java spring+hibernate webapp

EDIT2:  This is my concern as of now:
Should the Eclipse project structure be the project structure in Source countrol too? If so, then the base dir of the Eclipse project, will become the base dir of the source control project too

Comment: I wouldn't have a seperate `notes` directory for developer notes, put all such information in the developer guide. Also, unless you're in the habit of editing PDF files I'd store documentation/guides as .doc or whatever, just convert them to PDF when they are distributed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few notes:

- Avoid checking in IDE config.
- Use Maven style layout for source code (`src/main/java`, `src/test/java`)
- SQL can also be organised in a similar style i.e. `src/main/sql`.
- Depending on the complexity of the project consider separate modules (jars) for API, implementation, SQL, installer etc. Maven has built in support for multi-module projects:

  - [A multi-module example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/flex-dev-sect-creating-with-archetype.html#flex-dev-sect-multimodule-archetype)
  - [Multi-modules vs inheritance](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)

Comment: I tend to disagree on the first item. Sure: your build system should not depend on information *only* found in IDE config files, but having a nice "check out and just work" experience in your favorite IDE is not too bad a thing.

Comment: my team actually expects eclipse config to checked in. So that everybody can do a checkout in Eclipse SVN, and be up-and-running quickly

Comment: And src/main/scripts, src/main/docs. About the IDE config files: it's nice if they're checked in and "just work", but it's even worse if they're checked in and have information specific to a particular person's environment (which I've seen just as often).

Comment: @Kevin   why would you add docs in 'src'. It would be penalizing everybody who does a checkout of the project . Edit:  Didn't mean to sound rude.  just curious..

Comment: @Kevin: that's very true. Maybe "Be careful when checking in IDE config." would be a good suggestion ;-)

Comment: @rk2010 On my previous project our docs were written in Textile and converted to HTML during build. I guess `docs/main/textile` might be another possible option.

Comment: @Johnstok  Does that mean the Eclipse project structure, is the actual project structure in Source countrol too? If so, then the base dir of the Eclipse project, will become the base dir of the source control project too.

Comment: @Kevin @Joachim I have seen broken .classpath files a number of times, mostly due to variations in minor JVM releases from developer. Depends on your philosophy wrt how tightly a dev's environment should be specified.

Comment: @rk210 Eclipse shouldn't (needn't) dictate the layout of your repositiory. The layout of your repo will vary dependending on the complexity of the project (single vs multi-module), sdev best practices (automated build, etc.) and your understanding of how resources are related. I don't think there's a single 'right way'. Also, I would expect the structure to change over the lifespan of the project, as your understanding of the problem at hand improves.

Comment: @johnstok: I've seen that as well and that's why I've been so happy when Eclipse added the ability to specify the target environment in the classpath (i.e. say that the project depends on "JavaSE-1.6").

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find best practices that don't talk about src, test and lib directories, it should have been a hint that creating them was the commonly excepted best practice. I guess, you can create them under your dev directory.

Comment: Note that having a `lib` directory is only useful if your build system doesn't manage your dependencies for you. Maven/Ant+Ivy/Gradle for example would grab their dependencies from external sources. In those cases having a `lib` directory would actually be a sign of a problem.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: This makes sense. I was thinking about the question from the strictly Eclipse perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that most Java  IDsE ( Eclipse / IntelliJ / Netbeans)  support Maven . Also, teher are maven plugins for starting and stopping  most Webservers.

The simplest way for you to get started would be to

Step 1. Download and configure Maven . (Netbeans 7.0 ships with Maven support built in)

Step2 . Read up on AppFuse  at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-appfuse/

Step3. Find and use the appropriate AppFuse arcehtype for your project at AppFuse.